# Include StackApps in bottom nav on Trilogy sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, navigation, stackapps

I think we should include StackApps in the bottom nav on Trilogy sites, as it corresponds to all of them. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be added after the public beta ends and official release starts. Right now, it's still sort of an unstable playground and I think the SOFU team doesn't want people to wander there, not know that it's still in beta, and then decide to leave and never come back because it doesn't work for them.

Comment: But what if it does work for them? :)

Comment: @Maxim Hopefully, it does work. But the beta means that the API is subject to change, and the SOFU team doesn't want to frustrate anyone who thinks they'll need to constantly update their app just to keep it working.